# Random image slideshow, image transition fade in/out?

Tags: css

I am using this script for a random image slideshow, trying to display sponsor images.  The script works fine, I'm trying to create a fade in and/or fade out effect to it.

The script:

```
<script>
var delay=4000
var curindex=0

var randomimages=new Array()

    randomimages[0]="https://cdn4.sportngin.com/attachments/photo/5aed-137970385/cambria_large.jpg"
    randomimages[1]="https://cdn1.sportngin.com/attachments/photo/acab-137970605/9Round_large.png"
    randomimages[2]="https://cdn2.sportngin.com/attachments/photo/a12b-137971067/qdoba_large.jpg"
    randomimages[3]="https://cdn1.sportngin.com/attachments/photo/fcf5-137974579/chipotle_large.jpg"
    randomimages[4]="https://cdn3.sportngin.com/attachments/photo/3397-137974001/countryinn_large.jpg"


var preload=new Array()

for (n=0;n<randomimages.length;n++)
{
    preload[n]=new Image()
    preload[n].src=randomimages[n]
}

document.write('<img class="fade-in" name="defaultimage" height="294" width="294" style="display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length))]+'">')

function rotateimage()
{

if (curindex==(tempindex=Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length)))){
curindex=curindex==0? 1 : curindex-1
}
else
curindex=tempindex

    document.images.defaultimage.src=randomimages[curindex]

}

setInterval("rotateimage()",delay)
</script>
```

The script itself works fine.

This is the CSS I've tried for the image transition:

```
.fade-in {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

When the page loads the fade in works on the first image, but none of the subsequent ones [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/haydena/okpm4vtq/4/).  I'm hoping someone could steer me in the right direction.

Comment: Fade in applies to the only one image you have been created. After some interval no new image is created, but the source of the image changes - hence no fade in. What exactly do you want to achieve? Fade in for each image? Cross fade? And please format your code better, it's barely readable.

Comment: In the fiddle, the first image is faded in.  I'd like the subsequent images to fade in similarly (or not transition so harshly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution, add notes inside:

```js
var delay=4000
var curindex=0

var randomimages=new Array()

    randomimages[0]="https://cdn4.sportngin.com/attachments/photo/5aed-137970385/cambria_large.jpg"
    randomimages[1]="https://cdn1.sportngin.com/attachments/photo/acab-137970605/9Round_large.png"
    randomimages[2]="https://cdn2.sportngin.com/attachments/photo/a12b-137971067/qdoba_large.jpg"
    randomimages[3]="https://cdn1.sportngin.com/attachments/photo/fcf5-137974579/chipotle_large.jpg"
    randomimages[4]="https://cdn3.sportngin.com/attachments/photo/3397-137974001/countryinn_large.jpg"


var preload=new Array()

for (n=0;n<randomimages.length;n++)
{
    preload[n]=new Image()
    preload[n].src=randomimages[n]
}

//document.write('<img class="fade-in" name="defaultimage" height="294" width="294" style="display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length))]+'">')
// place the image on container:
document.querySelector('figure').innerHTML = '<img class="fade-in" name="defaultimage" height="294" width="294" style="display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length))]+'">';

function rotateimage()
{
document.querySelector('figure').innerHTML = ''; // clear image from container

if (curindex==(tempindex=Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length)))){
curindex=curindex==0? 1 : curindex-1
}
else
curindex=tempindex

//    document.images.defaultimage.src=randomimages[curindex]
// place image with different source on the container
document.querySelector('figure').innerHTML = '<img class="fade-in" name="defaultimage" height="294" width="294" style="display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" src="'+randomimages[curindex]+'">';

}

setInterval("rotateimage()",delay)
```

```css
.fade-in {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<figure></figure>
```

Additional important notes:

1. The key here is to create the element so the class will work. Now you are just changing `src` attribute so the class doesn't change (you can inspect that on browser dev tools).
2. On your code you use `document.write`. I change it to `.innerHTML` - both consider to be BAD practices on production. You should [create and append nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) instead. I use it here cause it fast.

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate your notes, both inside the script and in general.